# How to Properly Type an Async Function in TypeScript That May Return Different Types Based on Input Parameters?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, react-typescript

I'm somewhat new to TypeScript and I'm having an issue related to properly typing the return values for an asynchronous function. I want the return types to be based on the parameters I pass in.

***Here's an example:***

Below, the function `getData` is supposed to fetch data from a database or an API, and depending on the type parameter, it might return a string, an object, or null.

```
async function getData(type: string): Promise<any> {
    // ...fetch data based on type...
    // return data;
}
```

As you can see above, I'm currently using `Promise<any>` as the return type, which I'd like to avoid, especially because we're using strict mode.

***Going further with this example...***

Let's say that I'd like the function to be capable of returning three types of data:

1. For `type` `"user"`, it should return an object of type `User`:

```
interface User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
}
```

2. For `type` `"settings"`, it should return a `string`
3. For `type` `"none"`, it should return `null`

How can I properly type this function to ensure that TypeScript correctly infers the return type based on the input type? Is there a way to achieve this using conditional types, mapped types, or some other TS mechanism?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnLAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANz7lxURnphSgDmjBEVOMAA27Tj0YBfXLjABPAA4oAKoogBZOAuQBeHEwqYoZDAyaYwYHujFcQvJiAD2INuQrDhUxriIQEwnBQKDAUIAhWLsjcEGAAInBgcAA8ysgQAB6QIEToyADWEHJOMMiqSpoKAHwAFEzySmTKADS4AJRkAApQTlTAmKlqlQDaygC6VfoEwWAUUCA4kshweXAgcriSjEA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame Oh yeah, this makes sense to me as far as I understand generics. However, it looks like I'd still have to `@ts-ignore` the `return {} as any` line. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I didn't do any implementation of the function, just the types. `return {} as any` is a dummy code to prevent the compiler from complaining. In reality, you should check the passed key and return the respective type. Does it make sense? Should I write the answer?

Comment: @wonderflame Ahhh gotcha. ... Yeah, it makes sense. If you'd like to write the answer then please do. Appreciate it!

Comment: will do in a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's create a key-value pair type where the keys will be the name of the type and the values will be the types themselves:

```
type TypeMap = {
  user: User;
  settings: string;
  none: null;
};
```

Now, using typescript [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) let's make a function that accepts a generic parameter that is constrained to be a key of the `TypeMap`, and using which we will get the type of the return:

```
function getData<T extends keyof TypeMap>(
  type: T,
): Promise<TypeMap[T]> {
  return {} as any // dummy implementation
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnLAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANz7lxURnphSgDmjBEVOMAA27Tj0YBfXLjABPAA4oAKoogBZOAuQBeHEwqYoZDAyaYwYHujFcQvJiAD2INuQrDhUxrhgUQCFYuyNwQYAAicGBwADzKyBAAHpAgROjIANYQck4wyKpKmgoAfAAUTPJKZMoANLgAlGQAClBOVMCYcWpFANrKALrF+gRQYRRQIDiSyHDpcCByuJKMQA)